# Tracking marker clicks on Google Maps API - Analytics

Tags: api, google-maps, google-analytics

I'm trying to track the amount of people clicking on map markers with google Analytics, is this possible and if so, what are my options?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The updated [GA implementation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events#implementation) is the following:

```
ga('send', 'event', [eventCategory], [eventAction], [eventLabel], [eventValue], [fieldsObject]);
```

Example:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    ga('send', 'event', 'Videos', 'play', 'Fall Campaign');
    infoWindow.setContent(html);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why this isn't better documented but here's how I got it to work in the end. Add  gaq.push to the addListener function for the marker click. See the documentation linked by antyrat.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'category', 'action', 'opt_label']);
    infoWindow.setContent(html);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [Event Tracking](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/eventTrackerOverview.html) functionality at Google Analytics. More about tracking system you can find at official [documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/asyncMigrationExamples.html).